# Loading icons do not get larger as I increase width?

Tags: javascript

Why is this code not working? I am getting all circle elements and then increment every circle by 20 pixels, however they don't get larger at all. Console.log within that block does work so I am not sure what is the problem.

```
var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')
console.log(circles)
var width = 1;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
          clearInterval(id);
          $('#loadscreen').css('display','block')
          bar.style.display = 'none'
          $('#circles').css('display','none')
      } else {
          width++; 
          bar.style.width = width + '%'; 
          //loop for each circle
          for(i=0;i<circles.length;i++) {
            // increment width of circles by 20 pixels on every loop
            circles[i].style.width += '20px'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you have...

```
circles[i].style.width += '20px'
```

try replacing with

```
var initial=parseFloat(circles[i].getAttribute("width"))
circles[i].setAttribute("width",initial+20)
```

first line gets the width attribute and converts it from a string to a float.
second line sets the new value, so the old value plus the increment.

it's a bit more long winded but the width is stored as a string so needs to be converted to a number first before being able to use it as a number.

also using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` is a more certain way to set and get attributes of DOM elements as it doesn't matter where the original setting has come from (css or javascript)

---

in the example you gave above you are also calling the function before it's declared,
so `var id = setInterval(frame, 10);` needs to be moved to the bottom

Comment: and you used eval() for converting a string to a number...? Take a look at eval first, what it is and what it does. There are better ways to do it such as parseInt() and parseFloat(). Also the 'fool proof way' doesn't matter, as you set the width on the DOM using Javascript that won't matter as it won't be overwritten by CSS either way and this property will be added inline on the DOM anyway which has priority over CSS values anyway.

Comment: not true using 'elem.style.width' to get a value will fail under certain circumstances. But true using parseFloat is probably the technically correct way to get the number, but both works fine in this situation

Comment: That's right. My bad didn't pay attention to that, however using eval still stands. Just because it works doesn't mean that the way it should be. Execution of eval is slower as it is parsing a string to Javascript executable which is absolutely unnecessary and should not be used for converting a string to a number as for this specific purpose you have such function as parseInt/parseFloat.

Comment: just did some performance tests on eval vs parsefloat... never realised eval sucked so much - almost 300 times slower! thanks for the heads up

Comment: in the example you gave above you are also calling the function before it's declared, so 'var id = setInterval(frame, 10);' needs to be at the bottom